# Semicolon,Parentheses, and Curly Braces problems

Tags: java, android

When I try running this code, it gives me the errors `Error:')' expected, Error:illegal start of expression,Error';' expected`.Could someone help? I am new to java and android.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,       MainActivity4.class);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    final Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,MainActivity5.class);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(myIntent2);
        }

 }})}
```

Comment: Does it run or not compile?

Comment: It doesn't run and gives me those errors when i try

Comment: Formatting your code might help finding the mistakes by yourself ;)

Comment: I suggest you to use `alt+space` to avoid such.

Comment: Alt+space assumes he's using a specific compiler with that specific shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi colon and a closing braces is misplaced

last set should be `});}}` instead of `}})}`

```
public class MainActivity3 extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        final Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this, MainActivity4.class);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                startActivity(myIntent);
             }
        });

        final Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,MainActivity5.class);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(myIntent2);
            }

       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be

```
});
}}
```

instead of

```
}})}
```